# Vue combine event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following Vue event handlers with contenteditable:

```
<div contentEditable="true"
v-on:keyup="changed($event, current, 0)"
v-on:paste="changed($event, current, 0)"
v-on:blur="changed($event, current, 0)"
v-on:delete="changed($event, current, 0)"
v-on:focused="changed($event, current, 0)"></div>
```

However, I have many places where I call the same code and the code is getting long and verbose. Is there a way to combine event handlers? Something like:

`v-on:keyup:paste:blur:delete:focused` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can create your custom directive for this purpose. This sample may help you:

```
Vue.directive('wrap-on', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    // Keep function to remove the event later.
    el.wrappedEventFunctions = el.wrappedEventFunctions || {};
    el.wrappedEventFunctions[binding.rawName] = binding.value;

    for (var key in binding.modifiers) {
      // Check if element is a vue component
      if (vnode.componentInstance) {
        vnode.componentInstance.$on(key, binding.value);
      } else {
        el.addEventListener(key, binding.value);
      }
    }
  },
  unbind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    for (var key in binding.modifiers) {
      if (vnode.componentInstance) {
        vnode.componentInstance.$off(key, el.wrappedEventFunctions[binding.rawName]);
      } else {
        el.removeEventListener(key, el.wrappedEventFunctions[binding.rawName]);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This directive will add event handlers to the element. It checks if the element is a vue component; if it is a vue component it registers the events via `$on`. If it is not a vue component it uses `addEventListener`. You can change this behavior if you want.

And usage is like:

```
<input v-wrap-on.click.keydown="mixedCallback" />
```

Or:

```
<some-custom-component v-wrap-on.click.keydown="mixedCallback">
    ...
</some-custom-component>
```

Comment: With this solution $event is unavailable

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way, currently, to combine event listeners like you're describing.

What you could do is make this div it's own wrapper component (named 'editable-wrapper', for example) and emit one `change` event:

```
<div
  contentEditable="true"
  v-on:keyup="$emit('change', {$event, current} )"
  v-on:paste="$emit('change', {$event, current} )"
  v-on:blur="$emit('change', {$event, current} )"
  v-on:delete="$emit('change', {$event, current} )"
  v-on:focused="$emit('change', {$event, current} )">
</div>
```

And then you would only need to listen to one change event on the component (`data` is an object with `$event`, and `current` properties):

```
<editable-wrapper @change="changed(data)"></editable-wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a case that you actually need something else. I think you can use `watch` functionality, and it also handles "paste" and "cut" events (with mouse) and keyboard keys.

All you need is to set watcher to your property like so

```
data: {
    coupon_code: '',        
},
watch: {
    coupon_code: function(){
        console.log('watch-'+this.coupon_code);
    },
},
```

and HTML

```
<input type="text" autocomplete='off' v-model="coupon_code" >
```

[documenation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can declare events and event handlers like object and use v-on. In your case you declare this object in the mixin and use the same in all the templates.

```
let eventMixin = { 
    data() {
       return {
          events : {
             'keyup' : 'changed($event, current, 0)',
             'focus' : 'changed($event, current, 0)',
       }
   }
}

let component = {
   mixins: [eventMixin],
   template: '<div contentEditable="true" v-on=events ></div>
}
```

Hope this has helped . Vue v-on documentation you can find [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on), in which they have explained how to pass multiple events as object